# How do I stack a washer and dryer without a stacking kit?

Tags: dryer, appliances, washing-machine

I have a Samsung front-load washer and dryer that I want to stack.  The original stacking kit (SK-2A) is no longer available, but looks like this:

[image]

The replacement stacking kit (SK-3A or SK-5A) is basically just a couple of "S" brackets that go in the back.  This places the dryer further back than the washer.  Not only does it look strange, it also wastes precious space.

[image]

I assume the only purpose of a stacking kit is to prevent the dryer from accidentally sliding off.  Is there a safe way to do this without a kit?  I was thinking something as simple as a rubber mat would work, but I no experience with stacked units.

Comment: It definitely needs to be anchored no matter how you do it. If the dryer gets out of balance and it's just set on top,  it's going to end up crashing down.

Comment: call the manufacture's customer support.  The last thing you want is to have the dryer fall and pull the gas line apart.

Answer (score -1):

personally i'd take the chance with a 20ft endless ratchet strap wrapped around both machines.  with maybe a slim rubber mat between to increase the friction.